# How to permit all attributes besides user_id using strong_parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I would like to use something like that:

```
def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit!.without(:user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

will this work?

```
params.require(:answer).permit!.except(:user_id)
```

Comment: Despite the solution is correct, it's important to keep in mind (regarding the original question) that this is a dangerous solution. You should use a whitelist approach when dealing with permitted attributes, not blacklist.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti there are numerous circumstances where a whitelist approach really is excessive and blacklisting is in no way dangerous. Not every model represents a significant security threat. The threat needs to be assessed on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @ChrisNicola I add my vote to your comment, I think there should be a prohibit method as well as it makes more sense to me to block params that are dangerous

Answer (score 5):

I just want to put this out here, whitelisting is not DRY. Imagine a JSON API for a document based entry that could have up to 100 (or more) attributes (key value pairs). Generally the only pieces you need concern with are attributes that can escalate privileges like user_id.

Comment: Just can isolate the whitelisting from the controller and reuse it in multiple classes. That would fix the the problem.